# How to add the weather of one or multiple locations to the top panel?

Tags: wingpanel

How can I display the weather of one or possibly multiple locations in the wingpanel?

Searching the net brings up some indicators for Unity, but I don't think that's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I highly suggest you to try out `my-weather-indicator`. It will satisfy all of your needs.

Here's a screenshot showing the weather in Amsterdam:

[image: my-weather-indicator Amsterdam]

### Installation instructions

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install my-weather-indicator
```

It kind of has a *huge* dropdown menu once you right-click it that shows you the detailed info, but that's the only disadvantage of it I can think of.

Answer (score -1):

the my-weather-indicator isn't working in juno ?

after doing this little workaround it works :

[Missing icons in the wingpanel](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/16502/missing-icons-in-the-wingpanel)