# Missing icons in the wingpanel

Tags: wingpanel, release-juno

I made a fresh install of ElementaryOS 5.0 Juno (used to be running 0.4.1 Loki) and everything but one thing seems to work just fine.

On the top bar, were the keyboard layout, sound, connection, bell and power button are, used to be Steam and Discord icons when these programs where running, but now they aren't.

[image: As you can see, both Discord and Steam are running, but no icons are shown before the "ch"] As you can see, both Discord and Steam are running, but no icons are shown before the "ch"

How could I get them back?

[Edit: typos]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sadly, with Loki [support for system tray icons based on Ayatana Indicators was obsoleted](https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel/issues/96) and definitively dropped in Juno.

I found [a nice article](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/08/how-to-re-enable-ayatana-appindicators.html) which gives a workaround (tested working on my PCs).

Here are the basic steps:

1. Make `indicator-application` recognise `Pantheon`:

   ```
   mkdir -p ~/.config/autostart
   cp /etc/xdg/autostart/indicator-application.desktop ~/.config/autostart/
   sed -i 's/^OnlyShowIn.*/OnlyShowIn=Unity;GNOME;Pantheon;/' ~/.config/autostart/indicator-application.desktop
   ```
2. Dowload latest available release of `wingpanel-indicator-ayatana`:

   ```
   wget http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu/pool/main/w/wingpanel-indicator-ayatana/wingpanel-indicator-ayatana_2.0.3+r27+pkg17~ubuntu0.4.1.1_amd64.deb
   ```

   You might want to take a look at all the packages in `http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu/pool/main/w/wingpanel-indicator-ayatana/` and select the correct one for your architecture.
3. Install it:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i wingpanel-indicator-ayatana_2.0.3+r27+pkg17~ubuntu0.4.1.1_amd64.deb
   ```
4. Logout/Login (*might* be not needed, but just in case).

Comment: Awesome it's looking great!

Comment: Thanks for this post, is there any way to reduce the space between icons? they are very far apart from each other for some reason

Comment: it's work on me. thanks..

Comment: Note that you need to download the `.deb` package **without** `-dbg` in its name.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like @szx is wondering how to remove space between the icons. I hope it's okay to answer that, here.

Create a file **~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css** 
Put this text in it:

```
/* source: https://github.com/mdh34/elementary-indicators/issues/1 */
.composited-indicator {
    padding: 0 2px;
}
```

Logout, then back in.

Answer (score 0):

If somebody's looking for the current(ly) latest version 0.6 Odin, then

https://github.com/lafydev/wingpanel-indicator-ayatana

should be his friend. Just tested and seems to work all fine.