# Taskbar icons in juno dont work

Tags: icons, release-juno, notifications

in juno you can put the icons in the taskbar as in loki ?, example i install slack, discord, telegram... and the application icon does not come out. Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Daniel, this has already been answered. Check out this thread:

[Missing icons in the wingpanel](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/16502/missing-icons-in-the-wingpanel?rq=1)

Comment: I've tried it and it works, but the icons come out very apart from each other

Comment: I agree. We have to wait for Elementary to bring this back.

Answer (score 0):

Jorge, Ayatana should solve that. Skype, Telegram, Megasync, etc. They all work for me, just like regular taskbar icons.