# Bluetooth Tray Icon Missing

Tags: wingpanel, bluetooth

Today I have installed Juno.
Because it is important for me to have tray icons for programs, I used the answer in [this thread](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/16502/missing-icons-in-the-wingpanel/16503#16503) to get that functionality back.
However, after logging out & in, the bluetooth image disappeared, even though there is a placeholder and the functionality is still there as can been from the screenshot.

[image: bluetooth icon gone 1]
[image: bluetooth icon gone 2]

Does anyone know how I can get the picture of bluetooth back?
Thanks

Comment: Do you have other notifications enabled? Like Ayatana plugins maybe? Do you see notification icons?

Comment: It seems to be a problem with wingpanel-indicator-ayatana. I also had it installed and I had similiar problems, sometimes the icon disappearing completely including the placeholder and ability to open the menu. I uninstalled the hack and Bluetooth is working again. Sorry I have no more helpful answer.

Comment: I have the same problem with the bluetooth indicator missing.
To get it back I have to log out and log in again.
No wingpanel-indicator-ayatana installed whatsoever.
That's a wired behavior. Does anyone know why does this happen?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [reported bug](https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel-indicator-bluetooth/issues/64). And a [fix](https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel/pull/187) was recently approved.

The solution to your problem seems to be to wait for an update. :)