# PlexAmp, Notifications, wingpanel

Tags: release-juno, wingpanel, pantheon, notifications

Is anyone using Plexamp with Juno?

Are you able to access its App Menu? Under Unity the app makes an icon in the notification area and you can right click to get a menu for switching libraries and such.

There's a bunch of threads out there for other distros that talk about setting XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity and such. I tried a bunch of permutations of that without success.

I think the app is not using the right hooks for Pantheon/Wingpanel. I'd think this would be better in Plank from a UI perspective... Not sure why they chose notifications.

Any ideas for a work around? Helper app?

Thanks.

Comment: p.s. It does send notifications successfully - I see notifs when the track changes. It ignores turning them off and/or turning off sound in the Notification control panel actually.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/16502/missing-icons-in-the-wingpanel/16503#16503) can solve your isse.

Comment: That fixed the problem. Thanks!